# Get aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key in amplify

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am building a react app using `create-react-app`, which uses the javascript aws sdk to connect to dynamodb. I have it working locally, however I am unable to get this to work when hosted on AWS Amplify. My sticking point is I don't know how to pass aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key in Amplify to the react app.

Locally, I have a .env file with `REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. These of course are not defined in Amplify.

Inside package.json, I tried to set the variables in the build script. I even tried just with the access_key_id alone to rule out issues in setting two variables at once.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY react-scripts build",
  },
```

However, this results in an empty value for the REACT_APP_ variables.

I tried modifying the Amplify app build settings in two different ways both with and without the package.json change, also with no luck.

```
build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
        - echo "REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" >> .env
```

```
build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
        - echo "REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" >> .env
```

I don't know what else I can do or if I'm completely on the wrong track. I was pretty sure that the AWS environment injects these when the app is run within the ecosystem, because I've seen it work with a different app hosted on Elastic Beanstalk.

Ultimately all I need is the access_key_id and the secret_access_key for use in the javascript aws sdk to initialize the dynamodb client like such.

```
const client = new DynamoDB({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set env vars](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#setting-env-vars) in the amplify console if you want amplify to have build-time access to them.

I am sure you know this, but it is almost always a Very Bad Idea to include your aws credentials in your react client bundle in this way.  Your plaintext secrets will be readable by all your web users.

> As [Aws reminds us](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#frontend-framework-environment-variables): Storing sensitive values, such as API keys, inside these frontend framework prefixed environment variables is not a best practice and is highly discouraged

Comment: I'm pretty new to integrating AWS into a react app, and was following the documentation I found on the sdk. Is there another way of getting credentials for the dynamodb client other than using the access key?

Comment: There are lots of options.  You can obtain [browser-side credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html) directly.  But you might want to look at an  [Amplify full-stack architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/) where your SDK calls are hidden behind a backend API and your app has Cognito auth.  Amplify is powerful, but has beginner-friendly abstractions.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I haven't run into Amplify full-stack architecture before, and it looks like exactly what I need.